# Half Closing the socket prints bad characters

Tags: python, networking

My client sends a string "abcd" and half closes the socket (the write part). My server reads the data and appends it inside the list (collection) until end of file is recieved (half closed socket detected). Then it iterates through the list and sends the data.

My server code:

```
while True:
    try:
        sock,address = self.__mySocket.accept()

    except:
        print "Client is dead"
        break
    print "Client connect: " + str(address) 

    collection = []
    while True:
        data = sock.recv()  
        if len(data) == 0:
            break                  
        data = str(data[::-1])
        collection.append(data)

    for val in collection:
        sock.send(val)

sock.close()
```

The client:

```
sslsock.sendall('abcd\n')
time.sleep(1)                                
sslsock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)

data = ""
while True:
    data = sslsock.recv()
    if len(data) == 0:
        sslsock.close()
        sys.exit(1)

    print data
```

Now when I print the data on the client it just print garbage. I've tried using `pickle` and that didn't work either. Now, when I comment out the shutdown on the client and work my server around it just works fine. It prints the reverse of the sent data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In server Code. I put the for loop inside the if len(data) ==0 . And, It works. I 'm guessing that break statement was breaking out of even the outside While True. So, it never got to the point of sending.